# Simple daily returns pine script for tradingview

Tags: finance, trading, algorithmic-trading, pine-script

I'm trying this:

```
study("Hourly Returns")

close_prev = close[1]

return = return[1] + ( (close_prev - close) / close *100 )

plot(return)
```

But it displays nothing on the indicator.

The `return[1]` term is the problem, without that it shows the daily return but I'm trying to figure out how do a running total

Answer (score 2):

You can use two different approaches, one using any starting value like for example 100 and then calculate total return each hour by dividing present value by 100 or just use different formula. As I understand return[1] stands for previous return then:

```
presentReturn = (close - close_prev) / close_prev
return = presentReturn + return[1] * (1 + presentReturn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using the mutable operator: ":=" instead of "=" and initialize it first with some value (like 0)
Another option could be to use "cum" function:
https://www.tradingview.com/study-script-reference/#fun_cum

Answer (score 0):

You must first declare your variable before being able to refer to it :

```
//@version=5
indicator("Hourly Returns", overlay = true)

close_prev = close[1]

var float Return = na

Return := Return[1] + ( (close_prev - close) / close *100 )

plot(Return)
```